# Launch Maps app from Acrobat for mobile

Tags: javascript, google-maps, pdf, maps, acrobat

I have a PDF form with a text field pre-filled with an address. I would like to have a button beside the address that launches Google Maps (or other navigation app) with the address in the text field already searched.

I got this working fairly easily on my PC by just concatenating the address with the google maps hyperlink; this solution does not work on mobile.

Is this do-able using Javascript in Acrobat?

Comment: Acrobat JavaScript on mobile is far more limited than on the desktop. For example, on mobile, there is no app.launchURL method.

Comment: ...so even though you could concatenate the URL to go to, you can't execute it. See the link for what objects, properties, and methods are supported on the Adobe viewers.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/Mobile/iosapi/index.html